# Joint Optimization that is near-optimal in each component

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

Consider some convex and differentiable functions $f,g \subseteq \mathbb{R^{K}}$.

My goal is to try to define an optimization procedure such that it jointly minimizes both functions (or is at least near optimal). Of course, the solution to the joint problem is not necessarily the same as if we were to optimize each component individually. Let's denote the individual optimal solutions as
$$ x^*_f := \arg\min_{x} f(x) $$
$$ x^*_g := \arg\min_{x} g(x) $$

Now the problem is how to define some joint/"composite" function $H$ such that the goal is to find $x^*$:
$$ x^* = \arg\min_{x} H(f(x), g(x)) $$
under the additional constraints that $|x^* - x^*_f|$ and $|x^* - x^*_g|$ should be as small as possible.

---

The most obvious form would be $H = f(x) + g(x)$, or perhaps $H = f(x)g(x)$. However I've been thinking about this and it does not seem trivial if $f,g$ are complicated.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: I guess the first step may be to think about when we would prefer a) $H = f + g$ or b) $H = f*g$

Comment: I suppose one such solution is to first find the individual solutions $x^*_f$ and $x^*_g$, then simply optimize $H = |x^* - x^*_{f}| + |x^* - x^*_{g}|$. However I wonder if it would be possible to do this in one step, without knowing the individual solutions beforehand.

Comment: I think you could do it in one step, if you want to call it that, by formulating a bilevel optimization problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization  You would have two simultaneous lower-level problems instead of the standard one lower-level problem. I doubt such a formulation is going to be advantageous in practice though.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Since $f, g$ are convex, I think it may be possible to do something with Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions to reduce it to one step as mentioned on that page.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. But I still doubt it will be "better" than just solving the lower level problems first.